# Find minimum value of function which calls NDsolve

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I have defined a function which takes a coefficient for a differential equation as an argument, solves the differential equation with NDSolve, and returns the value of the solution at time t=10. I can plot this, but I can't seem to find the minimum value.

This code demonstrates the problem i'm having:

```
f[k_] := y[10] /. NDSolve[
    {y''[t] == -k*y[t], y[1] == 2 , y'[2] == 1},
    y,
    {t, 0, 10}
];
Plot[f[k], {k, 0, 2}] (* works great *)
NMinimize[{f[k], k > 0, k < .75}, k] (* fails *)
```

> The NMinimize fails with the error NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered
>   non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 1.'.

So how do I find the minimum of my function f?

Comment: Try `f[k_?NumericQ] := 
 y[10] /. First @
   NDSolve[{y''[t] == -k*y[t], y[1] == 2, y'[2] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}]`.  See the [pitfalls question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).  You also might want to consider `FindMinimum` instead of `NMinimize`.

Comment: Be sure to Clear[f] before you try Michael E2's solution, otherwise Mathematica will overload f with two definitions and use the less-restrictive one that you don't want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Michael E2's suggestion in his comment about using the argument pattern `k_?NumericQ` will certainly work, I would like to suggest a double interpolation approach because it is much faster.

```
ff[k_] := NDSolve[{y''[t] == -k*y[t], y[1.] == 2, y'[2.] == 1.}, y, {t, 0., 10.}][[1, 1, 2]]
AbsoluteTiming[
  f = Interpolation@Table[{k, ff[k][10.]}, {k, 0., 2, .01}];]
```

> ```
> {2.748679, Null}
> ```

```
AbsoluteTiming @ NMinimize[{f[k], {k > 0., k < .5}}, k]
```

> ```
> {0.075349, {-3.95571, {k -> 0.212177}}}
> ```

Now compare this with

```
g[k_?NumericQ] := 
  NDSolve[{y''[t] == -k*y[t], y[1.] == 2, y'[2.] == 1.}, y, {t, 0., 10.}][[1, 1, 2]][10.]
AbsoluteTiming @ NMinimize[{g[k], {k > 0., k < .5}}, k]
```

> ```
> {44.634075, {-3.95571, {k -> 0.212174}}}
> ```

The first result for the minimum is a little less precise, but much faster.

Comment: I think `FindMinimum` is even faster.  On this particular problem, it's even faster with `DSolve`.

Comment: @MichaelE2. Didn't get that far out the box when I was thinking about out-of-box ideas to improve the wretched performance of the OP approach :)

Comment: @m_goldberg could you explain a little why your double interpolation approach works out so fast, and how broadly it can be applied?

Comment: @ChrisK. I would say it's because `ff` in my method gets called many fewer times than `g` does in my version of the OP's method. But in this case, you should look at J. W. Perry's answer which shows an even better approach. However, it is a generally applicable trick and you might find other occasions where it will help.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, here is my implementation of `DSolve` and `FindMinimum` on the same equation. This does not address your `NDSolve` work but the result is relatively instantaneous.

```
soln = DSolve[{y''[t] == -k*y[t], y[1] == 2, y'[2] == 1}, y[t], t];
f[k_] := Evaluate[y[t] /. soln] /. t -> 10
FindMinimum[{f[k][[1]], 0 <= k <= 3/4}, {k, 1/10}]
```

I plot the same with

```
Plot[f[k], {k, 0, 2}]
```