# ParametricNDSolve[ ] and NMinimize[ ] in Combination

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions, astronomy

I have the following code that is used to simulate a spacecraft orbiting Mars, and uses ParametricNDSolve to vary the spacecraft's initial conditions using a parameter value `p`:

```
G = 6.672*10^-11;
m[1] = 6.4185*10^23;
m[2] = 1;
p[1] = {1000000, 1000000};
p[2] = {0, 0};
v[1] = {0, 0};
v[2] = {0, 2500};
tmax = 1000;

soln = ParametricNDSolve[{
    xm''[t] == -(G m[2] (xm[t] - xsc[t]))/((xm[t] - xsc[t])^2 + (ym[t] - ysc[t])^2)^(3/2),
    ym''[t] == -(G m[2] (ym[t] - ysc[t]))/((xm[t] - xsc[t])^2 + (ym[t] - ysc[t])^2)^(3/2),
    xsc''[t] == -(G m[1] (xsc[t] - xm[t]))/((xsc[t] - xm[t])^2 + (ysc[t] - ym[t])^2)^(3/2),
    ysc''[t] == -(G m[1] (ysc[t] - ym[t]))/((xsc[t] - xm[t])^2 + (ysc[t] - ym[t])^2)^(3/2),

    xm[0] == p[1][[1]], ym[0] == p[1][[2]], xsc[0] == p[2][[1]], 
    ysc[0] == p[2][[2]], xm'[0] == v[1][[1]], ym'[0] == v[1][[2]], 
    xsc'[0] == v[2][[1]] + 1000 p, ysc'[0] == v[2][[2]] + 1000 p},

   {xm[t], ym[t], xsc[t], ysc[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, {p}, 
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", AccuracyGoal -> 18, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 18, MaxSteps -> 10000000];

   ParametricEscapeTrajectories[t_] = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[{xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]} /. soln, {p, 0, 5,1}]], {t, 0, tmax}, Prolog -> {Red, Disk[{p[1][[1]], p[1][[2]]}, 50000]}]
```

Below is an ensemble of results created by varying the parameter `p` from 0 to 5 as shown by the `ParametricEscapeTrajectories` function.

[image]

What I'm hoping is to be able to do something similar to what was done at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85836/finding-minimium-periapse-distance-between-spacecraft-and-planet) link, where the NMinimize function was used to find the closest approach distance between Mars and the spacecraft (the so-called periapse radius). However, this time I'm hoping to be able to find the value of closest approach, time of closest approach AND the value of the parameter `p` that gives me the closest approach out of all possible parameter values between 0 and 5. So, for example, it may look something like this:

`{71729.9, {t -> 118.096}, {p -> 5}}`

So far I've tried things such as the following, but unfortunately have not been successful:

`NMinimize[Join[Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] /. soln, {t, 0, tmax}, {p, 0, 5, 1}], {t, p}]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NMinimize[{Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] /.  soln, 
           0 < t < tmax && 0 < p < 5}, 
           {t, p}, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]

(* {71729.9, {t -> 118.095, p -> 5.}} *)
```

**Edit**

Please note that your system is more elegant and easier to understand when written in vector form:

```
G = 6.672*10^-11;
m[1] = 6.4185*10^23;
m[2] = 1;
p[1] = {1000000, 1000000};
p[2] = {0, 0};
v[1] = {0, 0};
v[2] = {0, 2500};
tmax = 1000;

soln = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
   posM''[t]  == -G m[2] (posM[t] - posSc[t])/  Tr[(posM[t] - posSc[t])^2]^(3/2),
   posSc''[t] == - m[1]/m[2] posM''[t],
   posM[0]  == p[1],  posSc[0] == p[2],
   posM'[0] == v[1],  posSc'[0] == v[2] + 1000 r },
   {posM, posSc}, {t, 0, tmax}, {r}, 
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", AccuracyGoal -> 18, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 18, MaxSteps -> 10000000]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[Last@Through[soln[p][t]], {p, 0, 5, 1}]], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much belisarius. May I ask why simulated annealing is used instead of letting NMinimize choose its own method?

Comment: @indigoblue I found it faster ...